# falha no atributo .append ao inserir cadastro em lista - (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Consegui deixar o meu cadastro em loop que será encerrado apenas se o usuário digitar **N** ou **n**.
Após encerrar o cadastro o programa exibe as ***listas de cadastro*** e ***lista de sorteio***, porem, quando imprime a ***lista de cadastro***, retorna apenas o ultimo nome e valor cadastrado.
preciso que o programa me retorne conforme exemplo abaixo:
**Lista de Cadastro**
Maria doou R$30,00
João doou R$20,00
A ***lista de sorteio*** esta como eu preciso, multiplicando os nomes pelo valor doado.
Ex:
[Maria, Maria, Maria, João, João]
será que o programa não reconhece a instrução lista_cadastro.append([nome,valor])? como eu corrijo essa falha?
**segue o código:**

```
    import random
    lista_sorteio = list()#lista que vai receber o nome para sorteio
    lista_cadastro = list() #lista que vai receber o cadastro

    while True: #loop de repetição para varios cadastros
     nome = str(input('Nome: ')).capitalize() #captura o nome do doador
     valor = int(input('Valor: R$')) #captura o valor doado
      print('') # inserir espaço
      chances = int(valor // 10)
      for c in range(chances):
          lista_sorteio.append([nome])
      alexa = str(input('INSERIR NOVO CADASTRO? [S/N] ')).strip().upper()[0] # sai do loop cadastro
      if alexa in 'Nn':
         break #encerra o loop digitando N
    print('') # inserir espaço
    print('LISTA DE CADASTRO:')
    for d in range(chances):
        lista_cadastro.append([nome, valor])
        print(f'{nome} doou R${valor:.2f};')  # mostra os nomes em 
    lista_cadastro
    print('')  # inserir espaço
    print('LISTA DE SORTEIO:')
    print(lista_sorteio) # mostra os nomes em lista_sorteio
    print('') # inserir espaço
    ganhador = random.choice(lista_sorteio) #realizar sorteio
    print('O ganhador do Sorteio é {[0]}'.format(ganhador)) #mostra o nome do sorteio
```

Answer (score 0):

Se bem entendi qual era o objetivo (aumentar as chances de quem colaborou mais), deu certo fazendo o final assim:

```
print('LISTA DE SORTEIO:')
for nom in lista_cadastro:
    nomeSorteio = int(nom[1] / 10)
    for c in range(nomeSorteio):
        lista_sorteio.append(nom[0])

print
print(lista_sorteio)
ganhador = random.choice(lista_sorteio)  # realizar sorteio
print('O ganhador do Sorteio é {}'.format(ganhador))  # mostra o nome do sorteio
```

Sugiro analisar as diferenças para ver o que estava errado..

Comment: obrigado pela resposta Epx, no caso, eu imaginei um raciocínio no qual realizaria todos os cadastro e só depois retornaria  a lista na tela:
ex:

LISTA DE CADASTRO
XXXXXX
XXXXX

LISTA DE SORTEIO
XXXXXX, XXXXXX, XXXXX,  XXXXX

GANHADOR
XXXXXXX

eu consigo imprimir a lista de cadastro, mas não consigo imprimir a lista de sorteio sendo que ela multiplica o nome pelo valor doado.
ex:
lista de cadastro
maria doou 30,00
joão doou 20,00

Lista de Sorteio
[Maria, Maria, Maria, João, João]

Comment: alterei o código, consegui o retorno da lista de sorteio multiplicado pelo valor doado, porem agora a falha é no retorno da lista de cadastro, no qual não retorna todos os itens cadastrado, retorna apenas o ultimo item, poderia me auxiliar nessa falha?